# How to find the sum of nodes in a tree without recursion

Tags: python-3.x, tree

I've tried to solve this problem a few different ways.

The Node for my code is defined as:
A Node is an object
- value : Number
- children : List of Nodes

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, childnodes):
        self.key = key
        self.childnodes = childnodes

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Node({self.key!r}, {self.childnodes!r})'


testTree = Node(1, [Node(2, []), Node(3, [Node(4, [Node(5, []), Node(6, [Node(7, [])])])])])
```

I've gotten close to completing the problem with the code:

```
def sum_of_nodes(root):
    sum = 0

    while root:
        sum += root.key
        print(sum)
        root = root.childnodes
        print(root)
        root = root.pop()
        print(root)

print(sum)
```

However, it skips some portions of the code and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. The result of the above code is:

```
1
[Node(2, []), Node(3, [Node(4, [Node(5, []), Node(6, [Node(7, [])])])])]
Node(3, [Node(4, [Node(5, []), Node(6, [Node(7, [])])])])
4
[Node(4, [Node(5, []), Node(6, [Node(7, [])])])]
Node(4, [Node(5, []), Node(6, [Node(7, [])])])
8
[Node(5, []), Node(6, [Node(7, [])])]
Node(6, [Node(7, [])])
14
[Node(7, [])]
Node(7, [])
21
[]
```

Along with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/project1.py", line 191, in <module>
    print(f'itersum_of_nodes(testTree) => {itersum_of_nodes(testTree)}')  # 28
  File "D:/Documents/project1.py", line 108, in sum_of_nodes
    root = root.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

I've also tried the method taught at geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/ however, my children nodes are defined as a list rather than .right or .left and I'm not sure how to get the info I need out of it because of that. The code is:

```
stack = []
    sum = 0
    current = root

    while True:
        if current.childnodes[0] is not None:
            stack.append(current)
            current = current.childnodes[0]
        elif stack:
            current = stack.pop()
            sum += current.value
            current = current.childnodes[1]
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of while loop that traverses your tree without recursion. The main problem with this is that your nodes don't store the children individually, but rather as a list. This means that you need to be vigilant in checking how many children the node actually has.

```
def sum_of_nodes(root):
    sum = 0
    stack = []

    # While the current node is not none
    while root:
        # Add the value of the current node to the sum
        sum += root.key
        # Check if the current node has children
        if root.childnodes:
            # If it has two children, append the second child to the stack
            if len(root.childnodes) == 2:
                stack.append(root.childnodes[1])
            # Set the first child as the current node
            root = root.childnodes[0]
        # If the current node doesn't have any children, take one from the stack
        elif stack:
            root = stack.pop()
        # If we run out of children in the stack, end the while loop
        else:
            break        
    return sum
```